# Ito's Lemma in the multi-dimensional case

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes

Suppose that $S_1$ and $S_2$ are two stochastic process defined by : 
$$ dS_i(t) = S_i(t)(rdt + \sigma_idB_i^t)$$ for $i = 1,2$

How to find the stochastic differential equation verified by :
$$S_3(t) = \frac{S_1(t) + S_2(t)}{2}$$

Same question for :
$$S_4(t) = \sqrt{(S_1(t)S_2(t)}$$

For example, **let's consider $S_4$:**

For $S_4$, if we use $\phi(x,y) = \sqrt{xy}$, we have :
$$\phi'_x(x,y) = \frac{\sqrt{y}}{2\sqrt{x}}$$
$$\phi'_y(x,y) = \frac{\sqrt{x}}{2\sqrt{y}}$$
and : 
$$\phi''_{xx}(x,y) = \frac{-\sqrt{y}}{4}x^{-3/2}$$

Am i right ?

So the first part of **Ito's formula** should give us :

$$dS_4(t) = \frac{\sqrt{S_2}}{2\sqrt{S_1}}dS_1 + \frac{\sqrt{S_1}}{2\sqrt{S_2}}dS_2 + ...$$

I stop right there because i know it's already false... (i have the result and it has nothing to do with that).

It doesn't seem to be the right way to apply the Ito's formula...

Even for the second part, will it be something like :

$$\frac{1}{2}* \frac{-1}{4}\sqrt{S_2}S_1^{-3/2}d<S_1,S_1> + ... $$

Could you help me ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: all your partial derivatives are wrong

Comment: Could you explain why ... when you have $\phi(x,y) = \sqrt{xy}$, then :
$$\phi'_x(x,y) = (\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y})' = \sqrt{y} * \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$$ no ???

Comment: ooh, i have corrected the errors, does it look right to you now ?

Comment: yes, the derivatives are fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) For $S_3(t) = \frac{S_1(t) + S_2(t)}{2}$, there is no much you could do except,

$$ dS_3(t) = S_3(t)rdt +\frac12\left[ S_1(t)\sigma_1dB_1^t+S_2(t) \sigma_2dB_2^t\right]$$

2) For $S_4(t) = \sqrt{(S_1(t)S_2(t)}$, you may proceed as follows,

$$dS_4^2(t)=S_2(t)dS_1(t)+S_1(t)dS_2(t)+dS_1(t)dS_2(t)$$

$$= S_4^2(t)[(2r+\rho\sigma_1\sigma_2)dt+\sigma_1dB_1^t+\sigma_2dB_2^t]$$

where $\rho dt=<dW_1^tdW_2^t>$. Rewrite $dS_4^2(t)=2S_4(t)dS_4(t) + [dS_4(t)]^2$,

$$dS_4(t)= \frac12S_4(t)[(2r+\rho\sigma_1\sigma_2)dt+\sigma_1dB_1^t+\sigma_2dB_2^t]
-\frac1{2S_t(t)}[dS_4(t)]^2$$
$$= S_4(t)\left[\left(r-\frac18\sigma_1^2-\frac18\sigma_2^2+\frac14\rho\sigma_1\sigma_2\right)dt+\frac12\sigma_1dB_1^t+\frac12\sigma_2dB_2^t\right]$$